# AIR iOS scaling entire content, can't see anything

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

I've created an app with the latest version of AIR (16.0.0.272) and I'm trying to scale the content to fit any resolution of the iPhone from 4 to 6+
In desktop debugging I see all perfectly scaled changing the stage dimension to test my solution. Trying on my iPhone 5 I can't see the scaled content.
If I comment the resize function everything is ok (I see all the content, not scaled obviously).
That's my solution

```
private function resize(e:Event=null):void{
        w=stageW();
        h=stageH();
        var initW:Number=640;
        var initH:Number=960;
        //bg.img.width=w;
        trace(w+"/"+h);
        main.y=62;
        //main.x=w*.5-320;
        bg.width=w;
        bg.height=h;
        menu.bg.width=w;
        menu.bg.height=h;
        var divisor:Number = 640/w;
        main.width = Math.floor(main.width / divisor);
        main.height = Math.floor(main.height / divisor);
```

}
I have tried to temporize the resize call to test it on the iPhone but again after 2000ms I can't see anything.
After this I've tried with a listener addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); calling the resize above at the end of my operations of building UI and so on.
Can't figure why resizing a movieclip that contains my app content make it disappear from iPhone and not from the desktop.
Hope in a solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting the stage's dimensions?

Comment: stage.stageWidth and height, as usual.

Comment: Try it with stage.fullScreenWidth / fullScreenHeight

Answer (score 0):

Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY are what you should use for screen width and height on apps.

Note: the X and Y don't change with rotation - they'll stay the same when screen rotates, so your code to get screen dimensions will look like this:

```
if (bStagePortrait) {
    iScreenWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    iScreenHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
} else {
    iScreenWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    iScreenHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
}
```

Also use this code to prevent app from resizing or moving:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But I have another problem: the first time I launch the app the content doesn't appear, the second time everything is ok. I think it's related to time: cannot retrieve in time the display dimensions. I try to use setTimeout and see right now but I've tried in the past with no result. What do u suggest please? Thanks again

Comment: The code is running before the stage is available?  Listening for  Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a variety of reasons, your resize function could be getting called more than once.

```
main.width = Math.floor(main.width / divisor);
main.height = Math.floor(main.height / divisor);
```

will continuously make the main clip smaller. It may be better to use a constant or number for size calculation. I usually do something with scaling, though.

```
main.scaleX = main.scaleY = percentStageScaled;
```